# Need some guidance regarding a licensing script (BoxBilling)

Tags: php, licensing

I'm pretty new to the BoxBilling Licensing and to be fair, their not really providing any support!

I have this code to check a license which is working correctly however, if the license is invalid, it simply shows the word "Array" and if it is valid, shows nothing at all.

I need to know how I can set a different message rather than "Array" if the license is invalid and how I can basically kill the page (via die() or something similar).

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("opendb.php");

function getLicenseDetails($key)
{
$systeminfo = mysql_query("SELECT * from `systeminfo`"); 
$systeminfo = mysql_fetch_array($systeminfo); 
$url = 'http://clients.pbtechsupport.com/index.php/api/guest/servicelicense/check';
$params = array();
$params['license']  = $systeminfo[licensekey];
$params['host']     = 'localhost';
$params['path']     = dirname(__FILE__);
$params['version']  = '1.0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,              true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,        json_encode($params));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($code != 200) {
    error_log('CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE: '.$code);
}

return json_decode($result, true);
}

$json = getLicenseDetails('test');
if(!$json['valid']) {
print $json['error'];
}
include("closedb.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`print_r($json['error'])` to see what's in the array, then use its contents to output something more intelligent based on that. They presumably are returning information about the particular error encountered in their JSON.

Based on your comment, doing `print $json['error']['message'];` will display the error encountered. You could also do `if($json['error']['code'] == 1006) { print 'Your own custom error about the license here.'; }` if you'd prefer not to use their own text.

Comment: For example, if I suspend the license and then check using `print_r($json['error']);` it shows this message `Array ( [message] => License is not active [code] => 1006 )` Do you know how I can translate this to something readable to users?

Comment: I actually love you! That worked a treat! One final question... If i place `die();` below it, it kills the page even if the license is active... Anyway that I can make it only kill the page if an error exists? :)

Comment: Sure, put the `die()` in the `if` statement where you output the error message.

Comment: `$json = getLicenseDetails('test');
if(!$json['valid']) {
    print $json['error']['message'];
    die();
}`

Kills the page even when the license is valid?

Comment: It shouldn't, unless `$json['valid']` isn't what you think it is. Are you certain it's being set?